# How to draw spiral bubble charts with d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to draw spiral bubble charts with d3.js.
d3.js version is 6.6.0.

But, I can't...

Please, advice to me !

■■■■ Ideal status ■■■■

Bubbles line up in a spiral like this site.

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/fun-with-d3js-data-visualization-eye-candy-with-streaming-json/

[image: Ideal charts (i.stack.imgur.com)]

■■■■ current status ■■■■

My bubble charts is not on spiral.
Here, my bubble charts.

[image: Current charts (i.stack.imgur.com)]

This is my source code.

```js
var data_set = {
    children: [
        {name: "AAA", val: 50},
        {name: "BBB", val: 45},
        {name: "CCC", val: 40},
        {name: "DDD", val: 35},
        {name: "EEE", val: 30},
        {name: "FFF", val: 25},
        {name: "GGG", val: 20},
        {name: "HHH", val: 15},
        {name: "III", val: 10},
        {name: "JJJ", val: 5},
        {name: "KKK", val: 3},
        {name: "LLL", val: 2},
        {name: "NNN", val: 1}
    ]
}

var width=400, height=400;
var zoom = this.zoom

var bubble = d3.pack().size([width, height]).padding(0);
var nodes = d3.hierarchy( data_set ).sum(function(d){ return d.val })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; });
;
var bubble_data = bubble(nodes).descendants();
var no_root_bubble = bubble_data;

var max_val = d3.max(no_root_bubble, function(d){ return d.r ;});
var min_val = d3.min(no_root_bubble, function(d){return d.r ; });

var color_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min_val, max_val]).range(d3.schemeCategory10);
var color_scale_num = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min_val, max_val]).range([0, 9]);
var font_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min_val, max_val]).range([9, 28]);

var bubbles = d3.select("#content").selectAll(".bubble").data(no_root_bubble)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bubble")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x * zoom + "," + d.y * zoom + ")"; });

bubbles.append("circle")
.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * zoom; })
.style("fill", function(d,i){
    return d3.schemeCategory10[Math.round(color_scale_num(d.r))];
})
.attr("fill-opacity", 0.6);
;

bubbles.append("text")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
.text(function(d){ return d.data.name ; })
.style("font-size", function(d){ return font_scale(d.r);})
.style("fill", 'white')
```

best regards

Comment: The order of the bubbles (circles) in your sketch is acsending (from the center), while the order in your data is descending... Does it mean you want to put the biggest bubble in the center and then all the others one by one until the smallest bubble, or there is no meaning to the data order?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky

Thank you for your comment !  
And I'm sorry for any confusion.

Yes, I want to line the bubbles in ascending order from center.
Data_set is descending, but it is sorted in my code. (at line 23, var nodes = ~~)
I expect the bubles is linked together from center in ascending order and spiral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `buildSpiralLayout` function:

```js
const checkIntersection = (nodes, node, angle, radius) => {
  const x = radius * Math.sin(angle);
  const y = radius * -Math.cos(angle);
  return nodes.some(n => Math.hypot(n.x-x, n.y - y) <= n.val + node.val);
};

const buildSpiralLayout = nodes => {
  const ordered = nodes.sort((a,b) => a.val - b.val);
  let angle = 0;
  let radius = 10;
  return ordered.reduce((all, node, index) => {
    angle = (index === 0) ? 0 : angle + Math.PI / 3;
    while (checkIntersection(all, node, angle, radius)) radius++;
    const x = radius * Math.sin(angle);
    const y = radius * -Math.cos(angle);
    all.push({...node, x, y});
    return all;
  }, []);
}


const data = [
  {name: "AAA", val: 50},
  {name: "BBB", val: 45},
  {name: "CCC", val: 40},
  {name: "DDD", val: 35},
  {name: "EEE", val: 30},
  {name: "FFF", val: 25},
  {name: "GGG", val: 20},
  {name: "HHH", val: 15},
  {name: "III", val: 10},
  {name: "JJJ", val: 9},
  {name: "KKK", val: 8},
  {name: "LLL", val: 7},
  {name: "NNN", val: 6}
].map((item, index) => ({...item, id: index}));

const layout = buildSpiralLayout(data);
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(200,200)');

const items = g.selectAll('g.item')
    .data(layout, d => d.id)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('item', true)
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)

items.append('circle')
    .attr('r', d => d.val)
  .style('fill', 'blue');

items.append('text')
    .text(d => d.name)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
```

```css
text {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 10px;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="400" />
```

Comment: Wonderful !!

Thank you for your answer !!
And, sorry for lating repling.

It is very helpful !